# (M1 Mac) Geodjango GDAL: mach-o, but wrong architecture

Tags: python, django, gdal, geodjango

I  am trying to get GeoDjango running on mac os and have hit a problem with GDAL.

I have downloaded and installed GDAL without problem (Gdal Complete Binary) also installed from homebrew too.

Unfortunately when i was installed gdal with homebrew django can't find the gdal and throws gdal did not find error, after that. I installed from [KyngChaos GeoDjango Binary](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/frameworks/#gdal_complete) django find gdal but now throws that;

```
OSError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/gdal.framework/gdal, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Frameworks/gdal.framework/gdal: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/gdal.framework/gdal: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/3.1/GDAL: mach-o, but wrong architecture
    /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/3.1/GDAL: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

I think the Kyngchaos build not compaitable with arm platform

Any help would be much appreciated.

Django Version : 3.0 also tried 3.2 
Gdal Version : 3.2/3.1/2.4 All of them tried 
Python Version: 3.8 
Postgresql Version : 13 
Postgis/Geos installed 
gdal-config --libs:

```
-L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.2.2_3/lib -lgdal
```

Comment: The wrong architecture seems that you use the intel version. The build from source should be working fine if you use homebrew for native arm64.

Comment: Actually Homebrew install arm version successfully but django cannot find the hombrew gdal package, That's why i tried the KyngChaos build.

Comment: That's what happend when I remove KyngChaos builds;

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.

Comment: dirty solution, keep the correct architecture arm64 that works and add this to your django settings.py GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH='/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.2.2_3/lib/libgdal.dylib' . of course the gdalinfo --version should not give error. This is not for production as I assume you are not gonna use mac m1 for production

Comment: Also you need to have the same version of GDAL in your python

Comment: ofc is not production, It works thank you so much! (same steps also needed for geos add GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.9.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib' to settings.py)

Comment: that's great :)

Comment: For anyone who is getting `AttributeError: dlsym(0x102dde9f0, initGEOS_r): symbol not found
` error.
After you did everything listed before, make sure that the path in `GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH` ends with `libgeos_c.dylib`, not `libgeos.dylib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Find the paths of gdal and geos

```
find /opt -name "libgdal.dylib" -print 2>/dev/null
find /opt -name "libgeos_c.dylib" -print 2>/dev/null
```

Copy the output for gdal and geos (might be more than one, pick one of each)

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.6.2/lib/libgdal.dylib
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.11.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib
```

## Put it in the settings.py file

Put it in the DJANGO settings file, the default one is here but your milage may vary:

```
mysite
 ├── manage.py
 └── mysite
      ├── __init__.py
      └── settings.py
```

Bottom of the file:

```
# mysite/mysite/settings.py
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.6.2/lib/libgdal.dylib"
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/homebrew/Cellar/geos/3.11.1/lib/libgeos_c.dylib"
```

Answer (score 1):

dydl also [watches](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/ctypes/macholib/dyld.py#L30) `~/lib` folder, so the simplest solution is:

`ln -s /opt/homebrew/lib ~/lib`

Answer (score -3):

```
brew info gdal
```

which should give you something like:

```
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/gdal/3.2.2_3/lib/libgdal.dylib
```

put that into your GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH.

From here, you can debug it further by putting a break point in your exception's line.

Comment: Did this accepted answer actually work for anyone?  I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: No it doesn't work.

Comment: @RajaSimon Check the comments on the question thread, maybe these answers can help you.