# Install GDAL x86_64 version on M1Max

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, django-models, gdal

For a given Django Project (to which I'm new) I need to install GDAL **version: x86_64** because whenever I try `python manage.py migrate` on my Django project I get the following error:

> OSError: dlopen(/Users/name/lib/libgdal.dylib, 0x0006): tried:
> '/Users/name/lib/libgdal.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible
> architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))....

I tried to switch the architecture of the terminal from `arm64` to `i386` and download it with the that architecture but I get the same error.

In my `settings.py` the libraries **GDAL** and **GEOS** variable are declared as follows:

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/gdal/lib/libgdal.dylib'
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = '/opt/homebrew/opt/geos/lib/libgeos_c.dylib'
```

I searched and tried a lot of things, but nothing worked - have anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully solved it with the answer from Ronald ([M1 Mac - GDAL Wrong Architecture Error [Django]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561453/m1-mac-gdal-wrong-architecture-error-django))

I had to download both with a `arm64 architecture`, because my python was arch x86_64.